# Is there a way to hide "ignored" tags completely?

Tags: support, tags

So I've been trying to ignore the dnd-5e tag, but on the homepage - and really on any question search page - it just grays out the questions rather than leaving them out entirely. Considering the sheer volume of these questions, it hardly makes the ignore useful at all. Is there a way to actually just not see these questions on the front page or in searches?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can eliminate ignored tags from listings (including searches) entirely.

First, edit your ignored tags. You'll find the “ignored tags” menu in the right sidebar on mainsite if you're on [the question list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions) or [the front page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/):

> [image]

Ensure [dnd-5e] is on the list, then choose **Hide questions in your ignored tags**.

> [image]

That's it. They will now no longer show up in search, the front page, the question list, etc.